# ISTQB Advanced Level - Test Manager Exam (AL-TM; Core) they provide the answer to the question was wrong

Tags: test-management, istqb, test-techniques

I am practicing ISQTB _test management exam while going through the sample question i feel that they provide the answer to the question was wrong

This is the question

**Evaluate the status of the project against the defined exit criteria. Which of the following options shows the correct status? (2 credits)**

and the aswers are

```
A. Criteria A = OK, criteria B = OK, criteria C = OK

B. Criteria A = NOT OK, criteria B = NOT OK, criteria C = OK

C. Criteria A = OK, criteria B = NOT OK, criteria C = NOT OK

D. Criteria A = NOT OK, criteria B = NOT OK, criteria C = NOT OK
```

and they mark **B** is the correct answer

What I thought was A because this indicates that all the defined exit criteria have been met and the project is ready for closure.

Maybe I am wrong. Somebody, can you help me understand why answer B is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the question, the exit criteria have been defined for the project. These criteria are usually defined at the beginning of the project and are used to determine whether the project has been successfully completed and is ready for closure. The status of the project is then evaluated against these defined exit criteria.

Option B, which the exam marked as the correct answer, indicates that two of the exit criteria (A and B) have not been met, while one criterion (C) has been met. This means that the project is not yet ready for closure.

Option A, which you thought was the correct answer, indicates that all the exit criteria have been met, which would mean the project is ready for closure. However, the question specifically asks for **the correct status of the project "against the defined exit criteria"**. If any of the exit criteria have not been met, the project cannot be considered as meeting the defined criteria and ready for closure.

Therefore, the correct answer is B, as it correctly identifies that some of the defined exit criteria have not been met and the project is not yet ready for closure.

I hope this helps you understand why option B is the correct answer according to the given question.

Comment: thank you for the explanation now i understand where I get wrong decision